# How to understand "even" and "that" in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

https://macropolo.org/reluctant-stakeholder-chinas-highly-strategic-brand-revisionism-challenging-washington-thinks/

> And in that particular aspect, they are joined by some democracies, including, I would argue, **even** democratic India, **that** do not view it as the singular organizing principle of international statecraft.

1 Why not "**even** including, I would argue, democratic India"?

2 Can "that" introduce a non-restrictive attributive clause? I think the introducer should be "which".

---

Edit: I first thought the **that**-clause was a non-restrictive attributive clause modifying the noun which "**that**" immediately followed, i.e. "*India*". After reviewing, I noticed the verb is "*do*" not "does", so what the **that**-clause modifies is not "India" but "*some democracies*", and the **that**-clause is  restrictive.

Comment: 1) agreed 2) that or which is ok

Comment: @Sam I first thought the **that**-clause was a non-restrictive attributive clause modifying the noun which "**that**" immediately followed, i.e. "*India*". After reviewing, I noticed the verb is "*do*" not "does", so what the **that**-clause modifies is not "India" but "*some democracies*", and the **that**-clause is  restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

**even** is a focus-setter, and something of a concession, and here it would mean "and democratic India too, *though that may seem unusual or unlikely to you*". One would have to advance an argument to convince people of it.  The positioning of **even** directly before **democratic India** properly sets the focus of the concession on India, but your alternative would not be ungrammatical.

The concession about India is a parenthetical remark.  The *that*-clause modifies **some democracies** as you remark in your comment.  **that** and **which** are used  with both restrictive and non-restrictive clauses. The "rule" that says the one or the other must be used is prescriptivist.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the sentence to highlight the structure:

> [In some aspect] they are joined by some democracies, [**even** India],  **that** do not [have some point of view].

I agree the phrase *"including, I would argue, even democratic India"* is inelegant.  Yours is better.  However I think the writer's intention was to emphasize India is a *democracy*, and *even they* don't [believe in something].

Both *that* and *which* can introduce restrictive or non-restrictive clauses.  In this case, however, *that* begins a restrictive clause, since it's the main point of the sentence.

Examples of non-restrictive clauses with *that*:

> The ball *that we normally play with* is missing and we can't find it.
>
> The cat *that usually hangs out on the neighbors' porch* is on their roof.

Comment: 1 I first thought the **that**-clause was a non-restrictive attributive clause modifying the noun which "**that**" immediately followed, i.e. "*India*". After reviewing, I noticed the verb is "*do*" not "does", so what the **that**-clause modifies is not "India" but "*some democracies*", and the **that**-clause is  restrictive. 2 The two examples that you gave are restrictive, in my humble opinion.

Comment: @ZhangJian  So you think it would make it non-restrictive if I changed it to: *"The cat, **which usually hangs out on my neighbors' porch,** is on their roof"*?

Comment: Yes, according to what I have learnt.